# IRC protocol - constant client connections ok?

Tags: c#, wcf, sockets, irc

When I was experimenting with C# and WCF one of the things I kept reading about was how unscalable it is to have clients with a constant current connection to the server. And although WCF allows that it seems that the recommended best practise is to use 'per call' as opposed to 'per session' for instance management if you want to have any kind of decent scalablity. (Please correct me if Im wrong)

However from what I understand IRC uses constant client connections to the server and IRC servers (well networks of servers) are servicing hundreds of thousands of clients at any given time. So in that case is there nothing actually 'bad' about keeping constant client connections to the server?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C10k_problem

Comment: Actually, perhaps a more interesting example recently is web-sockets

Comment: imho you should not use WCF for IRC but pure sockets or a socket framework.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As long as you don't follow the one-thread-per-connection architecture, a server can support quite a large number of concurrent TCP connections.

IRC doesn't require much per connection state, beyond the TCP send and receive windows.

Answer (score 1):

If you need real-time duplex communication (IRC is a chat protocol), then keeping a TCP connection alive is a relevant option. However, TCP connection brings network overhead and operating systems have practical limits on the number of concurrent open TCP connections. WCF is commonly used in SOAP/HTTP/RPC contexts where duplex communication is not required, but certainly it offers suitable bindings and channels for that as well. To answer your question, there is nothing bad in keeping the connection open **if you have real-time, duplex requirements** for your communication.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, such architecture is feasible, but...  The ["ping? pong!"](http://web.irc.org/mla/ircd-users/1999/msg00097.html) thing was invented for a reason - to let both parties know that the other party is still there. You cannot actually tell if a client is idle, because it does not have much to say or because it is actually disconnected and you are waiting for a TCP timeout.

UPD: "hundreds of thousands of clients" is possible on IRCnet only because of server networks. For a single machine, the [C10K problem](http://www.kegel.com/c10k.html) is still an issue.

Comment: I'd also add that is suspect that the reason why there are *networks* of IRC servers is because the IRC servers themselves do not scale that well. In addition IRC is hardly used by anyone if you compare it to something like skype. So for modern apps that are catered for millions of users the advice to keep it connection-less sounds solid, but if you are going to have 10 clients at a time at the most, there is nothing wrong with keeping connection open all the time.